# What is the joda-time equivalent of few JDK TimeZone functions

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime, dst

what is the joda-time equivalent of below methods in JDK.

1. TimeZone.getOffset()
2. TimeZone.getRawOffset()
3. TimeZone.inDaylightTime()
4. TimeZone.useDaylightTime()
5. TimeZone.getDSTSavings()

My main idea is to store the below in database as suggested by most of the SO posts

1. time in UTC = joda Instant
2. time zone offset = which is the equivalent in joda?
3. dst offset = which is the equivalent in joda?

Also should i store the **RawOffset** or the DST adjusted offset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. DateTimeZone.getOffset()
2. DateTimeZone.getStandardOffset()
3. ! DateTimeZone.isStandardOffset()
4. ! DateTimeZone.isFixed()
5. Not sure.

If you just save the UTC instant and the timezone id (i.e. America/New York and Europe/London, not EST and GMT) then you don't need to worry about storing raw offsets. Especially as offsets change with annoying frequency. Let Joda and the tz database do all the work for you. So store:

1. ReadableInstant.getMillis()
2. DateTimeZone.getId()

---

With Java 8, just use `ZonedDateTime` persisted via `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`.

Comment: According to the below link, the suggestion is to store all the three offsets. May be I am missing something. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices/2533348#2533348

Comment: @Pangea - As the comment points out, this has already been done. The timezone id encodes every change in standard and DST offsets since 1970, so there's no need do do it yourself.